# Collections for getting data in the inserted order

Tags: java

Which collections can I use if I want to put employee details 1)as key value 2) without key value. In both case I want to retrieve data in the order in which they are inserted.Please Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple `List` implementations (simple value list storage), you can use the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class. For `Map` (key-value storage), use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). Both of these implementations will *preserve* insertion order.

Answer (score 3):

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

Answer (score 0):

**For Key-Value pair in ordered format**: [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

**For non - Key-Value pair in ordered format**: [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)